# Resolving file paths in my custom npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, command-line-interface

I'm trying to create an npm package (named **packer**) and experimenting with a similar configuration like webpack where-in the user can install my cli to build their package.

package.json for test package using packer:

```
...
"build": "pckr --config packer.config.js",
...
```

This is how my **packer-cli** looks for now:

```
#! /usr/bin/env node
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const customIndex = process.argv.indexOf('--config');
let customValue;

if (customIndex > -1) {
  // Retrieve the value after --config
  customValue = process.argv[customIndex + 1];
}

const configPath = (customValue || 'packer.config.js');

console.log(configPath); 
// prints "packer.config.js" when I run npm run build from the test package.
```

Although, how do I actually read the contents of the config file  from my packer-cli package? How do I build the path from my cli package to require the actual file?

Answer (score 0):

I digged into webpack-cli's code a bit and found the answer there itself. ([ref](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/blob/master/packages/webpack-cli/src/webpack-cli.ts#L339-L344)).

Basically the solution is to use `pathToFileURL`